# Automatic restart linux console app

Tags: android, c++, crash, raspberry-pi, autorun

I'm using Raspberry PI for automate my device. I need my console application (written on c++) on Raspberry to work without human for years. So I set up watchdog for rebooting every day, and run my app in autorun.

But my app could crash. I cant reveal the cause, and need to restart it fast. What way will be the best? May be I could write a "parent"-app, and call my as a thread in it, and control its working (but it could crash too)? Or maybe there is an existing daemon to do this? Or maybe someone knows, how to write Phyton app to do this, and run it in startup?

Comment: Create a service and let init.d deal with it.  There's no point in writting a wrapper to try and restart it when that already exists!

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily answering the question, but I think a better approach would be to use a tested utility such as "cron" to schedule a daily reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping a program running if it is prone to crash is easy enough, just using a shell script:

```
while true; do /bin/my_app; done
```

However, this whole approach won't be of any help if the application fails in some way short of a process shut-down. A common approach in situations like this to provide the application with some external access point (e.g., an HTTP server) that can be probed. Then some other process exercises the probe at regular intervals, and kills the program if it does not respond in a timely way. There are some very sophisticated frameworks for this sort of thing but, again, simple functionality of this type can be implemented just with shell scripts.